# How to call image inspect properties in hosted in ACR

Tags: azure, docker, docker-image, azure-container-registry

I have few images hosted in ACR, I want to inspect the image (Repository image) deployed in ACR.

For example I have one "hello-world" image in "test123" ACR. I want to inspect ACR image and read the json content of the image. I didn't see any suitable .NET packages or .NET SDK libraries.

how to run "docker image inspect test123.azurecr.io/hello-world:v3" using .NET SDK libraries by connecting AZURE Container Registry (ACR) ?

I have tried following packages, but I didn't see any support to get similar command using .NET Libraries.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerService/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Docker.DotNet/

https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker

Comment: the ACR is more on storage registry purpose, if you need to inspect may need compute or pull it to your local and perform layer insepction

Answer (score 0):

You can use the azure cli (az). It has a [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr/manifest?view=azure-cli-latest) command.

```
az acr manifest show --registry my-acr --name hello-world:123
```

Comment: I tried this command it shows me the manifest information of the repsoitory version. 

This command output is different az acr manifest show --registry test123 --name hello-world:v3

This command ouput is different "docker image inspect test123.azurecr.io/hello-world:v3"

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got answer for my question. We can use Http V2 API capabilities to retrieve Manifest or Config information to retrieve.

To get manifest information below is the URL's

GET {url}/v2/{name}/manifests/{reference}
[https://test.azurecr.io/v2/{imageName}/manifests/Sha:25635dfger4656454fggf](https://test.azurecr.io/v2/%7BimageName%7D/manifests/Sha:25635dfger4656454fggf)

GET {url}/v2/{name}/blobs/{digest}
[https://test.azurecr.io/v2/{imageName}/blobs/Sha:4534afdf33289988956565](https://test.azurecr.io/v2/%7BimageName%7D/blobs/Sha:4534afdf33289988956565)

Note: There are different digest's available for image. You will see one digest for entire Manifest and different digest for Config of Manifest section.

Please find below documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/manifests/get
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/blob/get